# Swift Array syntax

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, swift

Everytime I ask a question here, it's because I don't know what to search for, and I'm very sorry for that.

Anyway, I'm trying to create an application using Google Maps SDK, and I followed a very nice tutorial by Ron Kliffer on Ray Wenderlich's site. However, I want to customize it pretty heavy, so I'm trying to read every line and understanding what it does. Now I ran into a block, where I do not understand the syntax.

```
func fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: 
Double, types:[String], completion: (([GooglePlace]) -> Void)) -> ()
```

That's the function that's being called, this way:

```
dataProvider.fetchPlacesNearCoordinate(coordinate, radius:mapRadius, types: searchedTypes) { places in
  for place: GooglePlace in places {
```

I simply don't understand the completion: bit, and the "places in" bit. What follows is, if I'm not wrong, a "foreach" thing (or for in in Swift syntax.

EDIT: reformat

Edit2: And yes, an array of GooglePlaces is created in the function body, and the same array (I guess) is used in the forin-thing.

Comment: "For-In" is documented: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with the for-in, but confused by the single "places in" in the end of the function call, and the completion "argument" not being used (Since it's void?).

Comment: Then have a look at "Closure Expression Syntax" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html. "places" is the closure parameter, and it is used in `for place: GooglePlace in places {  }`.

Comment: Thank's a lot. That's just what I'm looking for.

Comment: There are a number of good blog posts and resources out there that explain closures. Martin R pointed you to the Apple doc, which is the best, but here are a couple more: http://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/11/a-basic-tutorial-on-functions-and-closures-in-swift/ and http://letvargo.mooo.com/a-beginners-guide-to-closures-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you, Roman. I am (slowly) understanding more and more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{    places in
     for place: GooglePlace in places {
         // ...
     }
}
```

is a closure. The general [closure expression syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) is

```
{ (param_1 : type_1, ..., param_n : type_n ) -> return_type in
    statements
}
```

When the closure type is known or can be inferred from the context then you can omit the parameter types, the return type (and also the parentheses around the parameters):

```
{ param_1, ..., param_n in
    statements
}
```

So the first `places` is the (only) closure parameter, and it is
used in the for-in statement.

Note that since the closure has the type `([GooglePlace]) -> Void`,
the `places` parameter has the type `[GooglePlace]` and
the explicit type annotation in the for-in loop is not necessary:

```
{    places in
     for place in places {
         // ...
     }
}
```

Comment: You're spoiling me, Martin! Thanks a lot, again.

Comment: So, am I right if I'm assuming this is the main reason for using the closure:
_Closures can capture and store references to any constants and variables from the context in which they are defined. This is known as closing over those constants and variables, hence the name “closures”. Swift handles all of the memory management of capturing for you._

since the closure itself contains references to some IBOutlets in the viewController.